# How to post list of objects in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, post

I have a method in a controller

```
    @PostMapping("/process")
    suspend fun process(
        @RequestParam("id") id: String,
        @RequestParam("names") names: List<String>,
        @RequestParam("repositoryUri") repositoryUri: String
    ) = coroutineScope {
    ...
    }
```

I want to send post query from front-end desktop application and I try

```
        val post = HttpPost(uri)
        val builder: MultipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()

        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
        builder.addTextBody("id", id, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY) // id is String, that is Ok
        builder.addTextBody("names", names, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY) // names is List<String>, error
        builder.addTextBody("repositoryUri", repositoryUri, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY) // Ok

        val entity: HttpEntity = builder.build()
        post.entity = entity
        httpclient.execute(post)
```

But the second param in the controller method (`names`) is not a string.
The builder has only methods addTextBody and addBinaryBody (but it doesn't seem to fit)

How can I do it?

P.S. I use apache

Comment: Why do you need multipart upload in this example? You can provide same data using json and\or query\path parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom format for sending a stringlist as a http form param.

Convert the list e.g. to a comma separated string, you'll have to reconvert the string to a list on the server side.

Or us json:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TextBody("names", mapper.writeValueAsString(names), ... )
```